Executing Liquibase multi-schema with same database migration in Dockerfile
My goal is to make a multi tenant springboot application using multi-schema system. In the local, I make this script to apply the database migration over multiple schemas.
# liquibase.sh
schemas="public private abstract"

# Loop through each schema
for schema in $schemas; do
    mvn liquibase:update -Dliquibase.liquibaseSchemaName="$schema" -Dliquibase.defaultSchemaName="$schema"
done

But, I met a problem. How to make a dockerfile?
This is the solution that I can think of
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17-slim

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY liquibase.sh ./
COPY pom.xml ./
COPY src ./src

RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

CMD ["sh", "-c", "chmod +x ./liquibase.sh && ./liquibase.sh && mvn spring-boot:run"]

This is the performance. '_mvn' is the image from dockerfile above. Compared to '_local' which only run executable .jar

